# vscode cannot debug python27 program after python extension update

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I wrote a python27 program, but when I debug it, it happens:
i.e.:the module "queue" could not be imported because it is shadowed.
Please rename this file/folder so that the original module from the standard library can be imported.

Then I adjusted the debugger program,and it reported that the debugger version is too high(version 3.6 or above is required),and a lower version of the debugger needs to be used.

Anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: While I don't know for sure, a possibility is that the IDE is dropping support for Python 2.7, which is no longer supported upstream. Have you considered porting your program to Python 3?

Comment: what are the names of your py files, I sometimes make the error of naming my py file the same as a standard module

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.